# How can replace a null value in a date column with "0"

Tags: sql-server, date

I wanted to replace a null value on a date column with "0" .I used this line of code to do it:

```
case when ast.AL_OpenDateShort is null then 0 else ast.AL_OpenDateShort end as AL_OpenDateShort
```

I got an error:

> "Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date"

How can I replace a null value in a date column with "0"

Comment: `0` is not a `date`. Why on earth you want to store `0` in `Date` column

Comment: try ..  `'0000-00-00'`

Comment: @J.Zend 0000-00-00 is not a valid date...

Comment: @Zohar Peled it's works to me...

Comment: @J.Zend - How did you check

Comment: Why is it significant that you want it to be 0 and nothing else? Could you consider using the minimum date supported by `datetime` type instead or some other date is unlikely to be used by your dataset?

Comment: The best thing you can do is leave it as null and display whatever value you want instead of null in the presentation layer.

Comment: Thanks, @Zohar Peled. How can I do your suggestion?

Comment: @prdp i have a column which data type is date,,,set value to null,then update with '0000-00-00'...sorry if i missunderstood the question,,,,

Comment: That depends on your presentation layer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @dt datetime = '2016-07-11'
declare @dt2 datetime = null

select case when @dt is null then '0' else cast(@dt as varchar(11)) end dt,
       case when @dt2 is null then '0'  else cast(@dt2 as varchar(11)) end dt2
```

returns

```
dt          dt2
Jul 11 2016 0
```

Comment: Thank you very mutch @P.Salmon

Comment: That's not a date, it's a string... :P

Answer (score 1):

You cant have `0` as a `DATE`, `0` is an `INT`. You might have seen `0` being used as a `DATE` (As in `DATEDIFF(...)`) but this is actually the date `19000101`.

Anyway, I've no idea what you're really after but this gives you a Date in ISO 8601 `INT` format, or 0 if null.

You might want to change the `INT` type to a `VARCHAR` and the format to suit. But then, you won't have a date, you'll have a string.

```
COALESCE(CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),MyDate, 112)),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(myColumn, 0 ) FROM myTable
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not a valid answer to my question.

Comment: @mql4beginner - Even your question is not too valid. Why you want to store `0` in `DATE` column

Comment: @Prdp, I need to statistical package that doesn't  take nulls.

Comment: @mql4beginner that doesn't mean you need 0 though. As I suggested in my other comment, consider using the minimum supported date value for `datetime` type or some other date that is unused by your dataset.

Comment: Hey @Jonathon Ogden , I don't want to use out of context data.

Comment: @mql4beginner I understand, but 0 is also "out of context" in the sense it's not a valid `datetime` value, so it's not an option for you (based on my own experience).